# Multiprocessing Running Slower than a Single Process

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm attempting to use multiprocessing to run many simulations across multiple processes; however, the code I have written only uses 1 of the processes as far as I can tell.

*Updated*

I've gotten all the processes to work (I think) thanks to @PaulBecotte ; however, the multiprocessing seems to run significantly slower than its non-multiprocessing counterpart.

For instance, not including the function and class declarations/implementations and imports, I have:

```
def monty_hall_sim(num_trial, player_type='AlwaysSwitchPlayer'):
    if player_type == 'NeverSwitchPlayer':
        player = NeverSwitchPlayer('Never Switch Player')
    else:
        player = AlwaysSwitchPlayer('Always Switch Player')

    return (MontyHallGame().play_game(player) for trial in xrange(num_trial))

def do_work(in_queue, out_queue):
    while True:
        try:
            f, args = in_queue.get()
            ret = f(*args)
            for result in ret:
                out_queue.put(result)
        except:
            break

def main():
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.ERROR)

    always_switch_input_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    always_switch_output_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    total_sims = 20
    num_processes = 5
    process_sims = total_sims/num_processes

    with Timer(timer_name='Always Switch Timer'):
        for i in xrange(num_processes):
            always_switch_input_queue.put((monty_hall_sim, (process_sims, 'AlwaysSwitchPlayer')))

        procs = [multiprocessing.Process(target=do_work, args=(always_switch_input_queue, always_switch_output_queue)) for i in range(num_processes)]

        for proc in procs:
            proc.start()

        always_switch_res = []
        while len(always_switch_res) != total_sims:
            always_switch_res.append(always_switch_output_queue.get())

        always_switch_success = float(always_switch_res.count(True))/float(len(always_switch_res))

    print '\tLength of Always Switch Result List: {alw_sw_len}'.format(alw_sw_len=len(always_switch_res))
    print '\tThe success average of switching doors was: {alw_sw_prob}'.format(alw_sw_prob=always_switch_success)
```

which yields:

```
    Time Elapsed: 1.32399988174 seconds
    Length: 20
    The success average: 0.6
```

However, I am attempting to use this for `total_sims = 10,000,000` over `num_processes = 5`, and doing so has taken significantly longer than using 1 process (1 process returned in ~3 minutes). The non-multiprocessing counterpart I'm comparing it to is:

```
def main():
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.ERROR)

    with Timer(timer_name='Always Switch Monty Hall Timer'):
        always_switch_res = [MontyHallGame().play_game(AlwaysSwitchPlayer('Monty Hall')) for x in xrange(10000000)]

        always_switch_success = float(always_switch_res.count(True))/float(len(always_switch_res))

    print '\n\tThe success average of not switching doors was: {not_switching}' \
          '\n\tThe success average of switching doors was: {switching}'.format(not_switching=never_switch_success,
                                                                               switching=always_switch_success)
```

Comment: Your child processes- they consume from the input queue and export to the output queue? You only ever put 4 (now 5) messages into the queue, so shouldn't that be the number of outputs you get?

Comment: Hi @PaulBecotte , new to Python so I probably messed up the above code completely. What I'm attempting to do is make an input queue that has 5 tuples (fcn_name, (num_of_trials_to_perform,)) where the function is a Monty Hall simulation and the number of trials to perform is the number of Monty Hall simulations to do within the Monty Hall function for the child process. So with 20 simulations total, I want 5 tuples with (fcn_name, (4,)) and then use each of those tuples in a child process. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT- you changed some stuff, let me try and explain a bit better.

Each message you put into the input queue will cause the monty_hall_sim function to get called and send num_trial messages to the output queue.

So your original implementation was right- to get 20 output messages, send in 5 input messages.

However, your function is slightly wrong.

```
for trial in xrange(num_trial):
    res = MontyHallGame().play_game(player)
    yield res
```

This will turn the function into a generator that will provide a new value on each next() call- great! The problem is here

```
while True:
    try:
        f, args = in_queue.get(timeout=1)
        ret = f(*args)
        out_queue.put(ret.next())
    except:
        break
```

Here, on each pass through the loop you create a NEW generator with a NEW message. The old one is thrown away. So here, each input message only adds a single output message to the queue before you throw it away and get another one. The correct way to write this is-

```
while True:
    try:
        f, args = in_queue.get(timeout=1)
        ret = f(*args)
        for result in ret:
            out_queue.put(ret.next())
    except:
        break
```

Doing it this way will continue to yield output messages from the generator until it finishes (after yielding 4 messages in this case)

Comment: Thanks, that got me to the output I've been trying to get @PaulBecotte ! However, my code still runs slower than the same functionality implemented with 1 process for 10,000,000 total simulations, which is odd.

Comment: You did add a full 1 second wait as the terminal condition for your processes. That seems likely to dominate processing speeds on a program of this complexity.

Comment: I've followed your advice and taken out the timeouts of 1 second in both get() calls and I changed the procs list of processes to a generator, which lowered the time taken so that it was just double the time taken by the same program using 1 process @PaulBecotte . Also, adding more processes doesn't change the time taken.

Comment: Your design has a couple issues. The most obvious to me is that you fill up the queue before starting the child processes- you should probably be starting your process pool first. Second, the specific thing you are doing is a very tiny bit of work for each message passed- so you take the overhead of serializing the message and passing it back and forth to only do a tiny bit of processing. Maybe have each message lead to thousands of iterations?

Comment: I thought that my current code is having each child process call the `do_work` function, which calls the `monty_hall_sim` function to create thousands of simulations and store them in the generator, and then stores the items of the generator in the output. Am I not understanding how the program is truly working @PaulBecotte ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try import “process “ under some if statements

Comment: In the monty_hall_sim function @26099 ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my code to run significantly faster by changing monty_hall_sim's return to a list comprehension, having do_work add the lists to the output queue, and then extend the results list of main with the lists returned by the output queue. Made it run in ~13 seconds.